# How to avoid keyboard events handling to be inherited by all the pages in the stack (Ionic)?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have a page, in an app made with Ionic 3. Let's call it Page1. Page1 requires a certain keyboard handling, so in my Page1 I have:

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvents($event)'
  }
})
export class Page1{
  ...
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if(event.which == 13){
    console.log("You pressed Enter!");
  }
}
```

So far so good. Then on Page1 there's a button 'go to Page2' and clicking it cause

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page2, {});
```

That is, cause Page2 to be presented and to be put on pages stack, over Page1.

When the user is presented Page2, still pressing 'Enter' button on keyboard cause the function handleKeyboardEvent to be executed and the console log to be logged on console, but what I need is the keyboard handling to work only on the page where I put it and not on all the pages actually on the stack.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of more elegant solution, one can be

```
handleKeyboardEvents(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
  if(this.navCtrl.getActive().name=="Page1"){
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your project structure it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing and why. 
I might try having the key events on the inputs / elements themselves on a page by page basis, rather than using

```
'(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvents($event)'
```

This might help with your enter detection as well. Try this on your elements, and define the function within each page. ie

```
(keyup.enter)="myFunctionToRun()"
```

Comment: Could be an idea, but is too specific. In my case, for example, I have an entire html custom keyboard to manage and it's not possible to do this. Thank you anyway :)